# I already created a customized listview showing data using sqlite database now i want to move to next activity when clicked on item in listview

Tags: android, sqlite, listview

As my listview is Dynamic because data is coming from SQLite Database so i want to open a new activity when any one taps on listview.
Any help is appreciated.

Comment: show your code please

Answer (score 0):

Implement this.

```
lv.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener()
    {
        @Override 
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1,int position, long arg3)
        { 
          //write your Intent code to move to another class here.
           Intent i= new Intent(currentClass.this, NextClass.class);
           startActivity(i);
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

set click listener on the row view .. and acc to position pass the data to next activity.

Answer (score 0):

```
listview.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener()
        {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                                    int position, long id) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                Intent i= new Intent(SourceClass.this, DestinationClass.class);
                startActivity(i);
            }
        });
```